# How can we get the coordinates with the help of distance traveled and direction of movement?

Tags: python, arrays, list, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have an array

`sensor_data=[10,0,5,1,10,1,20,1,20,1,15]`

Now in this:

0 means that the robot/drone has taken a right turn and

1 means that the robot/drone has taken a left turn.

The remaining of the digits are distances traveled.

So according to the above array, first the robot/drone travels a distance of 10 cm. Then it turn right. After turning right the robot/drone travels 5 cm and then it takes a left. After taking a left turn it travels 10 cm and so on. So initially the robot/drone is at (0,0). Then it travels straight i.e in the y direction.

Thus the coordinates would be (0,10). Then after the right turn and after traveling 5 cm, the coordinates would be (-5,10). Following such a pattern, the rest of the coordinates are: (-5,20),(15,20) and (15,0). What code can be written so that these coordinates can be generated from the above given array.

Comment: You have to make an attempt first before you ask people to solve your homework for you.

Comment: Already working on it mate! Not one of those who would put his responsibility on someone else!

Comment: this is proving a bit trickier than I though but I'll have it in about 10 mins I think...Kinda like doing linear algebra in cartesian coordinates for fun.

Comment: Okay! Haha ikr!

Comment: the first 10cm is in x-direction or y direction ??

Comment: In y direction. The first measurement is always in y direction for my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chew on this until you figure it out lol.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos,sin,pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Convert data into floats, for 
sensor_data = tuple(map(lambda x: float(x),[10,0,5,1,10,1,20,1,20,1,15]))

# Start at 0,0 in a 2D plane and start out in x-Direction
Starting_Position = np.array((0.,0.))
Starting_Direction = np.array((1.,0.))



def Rotation_Matrix(direction):

    '''Can be expanded for any angle of rotation in a 2D plane. Google rotation matrix in 2D space.'''

    a = {'left':pi/2,'right':-pi/2}[direction]

    matrix = np.array(((round(cos(a),7),round(-sin(a),7)),
                       (round(sin(a),7),round(cos(a),7))))

    return matrix



def DronePosition(Number_input,Current_Position,Current_Direction):

    if Number_input == 1.:
        New_Direction = Current_Direction.dot(Rotation_Matrix('left'))
        New_Position = Current_Position
    elif Number_input == 0.:
        New_Direction = Current_Direction.dot(Rotation_Matrix('right'))
        New_Position = Current_Position
    else:
        New_Position = Current_Position + Current_Direction*Number_input
        New_Direction = Current_Direction


    return New_Position,New_Direction

Drone_Path = np.zeros(shape=(len(sensor_data),2))

for step in range(len(sensor_data)):
    Drone_Path[step,0] = Starting_Position[0] 
    Drone_Path[step,1] = Starting_Position[1] 
    Starting_Position, Starting_Direction = DronePosition(sensor_data[step],Starting_Position,Starting_Direction)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

ax.plot(Drone_Path[:,0],Drone_Path[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did some potentially funny stuff for a beginner, like using a round() function in the Rotation_Matrix entries (that's just because of float inprecision. Something, that should be 0 becomes something like 1.6e-17 or something). If you have some questions, just ask them. Seems the mods are letting this one slide, so ask away.